# Assets are not properly assembled when testing with cucumber

Tags: cucumber, capybara, asset-pipeline, jrubyonrails

I'm trying to run some cucumber tests in my jruby-on-rails project, but the assembly pipeline seems to cause issues.

When I look at the generated page with the capybara function `save_and_open_page`, there are no ending tags `</script>` for referenced my javascripts. So the `yield` is called in a very funny place and the page ends up rendered completely wrong.

I'm using rails 3.1.4 at the moment. Anyone else ever had this issue?

PS: everything works fine when running the project in development mode. The problem just occurs in tests.